# SQL latest audit changes

Tags: mysql

```
    select 

    LEFT (REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''), 4) PROJECT_CODE,

    CASE    WHEN LEN(REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''))  >4 THEN RIGHT(REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''), 2)    ELSE ''  END as PROJECT_PHASE,
    KEY_2,  
    FIELD_NAME,
   AUDIT_OLD_VALUE,
   AUDIT_NEW_VALUE,
   UNIQUE_RID
 FROM TBADT_AUDIT_TRAIL 

where Key_1 like 'WKSCHART'
and
Audit_Date between '2017-06-13' and '2017-06-16'

ORDER BY  PROJECT_CODE, PROJECT_PHASE, FIELD_NAME
```

- so i need the latest changes made to `FIELD_NAME` col. for example below, under col `key_2`, 3332P6; Field_Name '`Submission`', was modified 3 times within my extract date. although not duplicate i need just the latest modification which is UNIQUE_RID 47271398. is that possible?

Comment: how do i attach my result set?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query